# How to change protocol to typealias or closure

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, protocols

In my code I do not want to use protocol I want use closures but I couldn't get it done because I am new on Swift.

Here is the example of class

```
class SplashPresenterImp: SplashPresenter, OnFinishedListener {

    private var interactor: SplashInteractor
    private var splashNetworkProtocol: SplashNetworkProtocol


    init() {
        interactor = SplashNetworking()
    }

    func startDownloadConfigs(splashNetworkProtocol: SplashNetworkProtocol){
        if  interactor != nil {
            interactor.loadConfigs(listener: self)
            self.splashNetworkProtocol = splashNetworkProtocol
        }
    }

    func startDownloadDictionary(splashNetworkProtocol: SplashNetworkProtocol) {
        if  interactor != nil {
            interactor.loadDictionary(listener: self)
            self.splashNetworkProtocol = splashNetworkProtocol
        }
    }

    func onFinishedGetDictionary(dictionary: Dictionary) {
        //save dictionary
        if splashNetworkProtocol != nil {
            splashNetworkProtocol.onSuccess()
        }
    }
    func onFinishedGetConfigs(config: Config) {
        //save configs
        if splashNetworkProtocol != nil {
            splashNetworkProtocol.onSuccess()
        }
    }
    func onFinishedWithError(error: AMError) {
        if splashNetworkProtocol != nil {
            splashNetworkProtocol.onError(error: error)()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the protocol

```
protocol SplashNetworkProtocol: class {
    func onSuccess()
    func onError(error: AMError)
}
```

What I want to have on my viewcontroller to have closure when downloadConfig is complete to start downloadDictionary.

I know how it handle on Java here is the code

```
mPresenter.startDownloadConfigs(new SplashNetworkProtocol() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                downloadDictionary();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final AMError error) {

            }
        });
```

I want to have same result in swift. Is anyone can give me advice how to do this?

More clearly I want get rid of `SplashNetworkProtocol` and use only closure.

swift result should be this

```
mPresenter.startDownloadConfigs(onSuccess: {} onError{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
func startDownloadDictionary(onSuccess: () -> Void, onError: () -> Void)
```

But even better to use a single closure that handles both success and error. For instance, with an error as an optional parameter:

```
func startDownloadDictionary(onCompletion: (Error?) -> Void)
```

A full example:

```
func someOtherFunc() {
    startDownloadDictionary(onCompletion: {(error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        //no error
    })
}

func startDownloadDictionary(onCompletion: (Error?) -> Void)
{
    //dostuff
    var error: Error?
    // if error happens, create it
    onCompletion(error)
}
```

If you need help with Swift closure syntax, this is a good resource:
http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/

Comment: what should I change on SplashPresenterImp class? I want declare something instead SplashNetworkProtocol

Comment: All the information you need is in the above answer.

Comment: but callback should I call on onFinishedGetDictionary or onFinishedGetConfigs

Comment: I don't want it call on startDownloadDictionary method

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it? call closure after onFinishedGetConfigs get called?